# Fire Departments covering area

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Given a set of points (GPS coordinates), and a polygon that contains all those points, can one determine how well those points are covering the area or what the longest distance from any location within the polygon to the nearest point is?

For example, if I have all fire departments within the city boundary of New York, I want to know how long a fire truck has to drive (in case of an emergency) in the worst case.

Any ideas on what the name of this problem is or what this problem can be reduced to? Or are there any existing algorithms for that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First construct the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the set of sites (GPS coordinates). The Voronoi diagram is a data structure representing a partition of the plane into cells, one cell for each site, such that each site's cell consists of all the points closer to that site than to any other site.

Constructing the Voronoi diagram can be done in `O(nlog(n))` using [Fortune's sweep-line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) where `n` is the number of input sites.

Then iterate over the Voronoi cells. Each cell is a polygon. For each cell compute the distance between the cell's site and each of the polygon's vertices. The longest distance between a site and a vertex of the site's cell is the longest distance one would have to walk in order to reach the site.

The running time of the algorithm is `O(nlog(n))` as the second phase of the algorithm (iterating over the vertices of each Voronoi cell) requires only linear time. This is because the total number of vertices in the whole diagram grows linearly with the number of sites. Namely, it's not too difficult to show using [Euler's formula for planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) that the total number of Voronoi vertices is bounded from above by `2n-5`.

You can find some open source implementations of Fortune's algorithm on the web. [This one](http://skynet.ie/~sos/mapviewer/voronoi.php) for instance.

Comment: Thank you, great answer!